# SQL query with Table variable/Temp Table - which one good in performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, sqlperformance, table-variable

SQL Questions:
Is this insert query is good in performance ?

---

UserIds List is variable, its length mybe 10, 20 ... till 500.

```
WITH Users
  AS (SELECT [Id] from [electro].[User] Where [Id] IN (4438,15473,22497,22494,4425,4426,22496))
  INSERT INTO [electro].[ElectronicCorrespondenceInbox] ([UserId], [ElectronicCorrespondenceId], [CreatedAt])
  SELECT [User].[Id], [Corrs].[Id], GETDATE()
FROM [electro].[ElectronicCorrespondence] AS [Corrs], [Users] AS [User]
WHERE [Corrs].[Published] = 0;
```

**Or**

---

Creating temp variable contains users ids is good idea ?

Option 2# with Table variable:

```
DECLARE @USERS TABLE
([UserId] INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @USERS
VALUES (2350), (4438), (15473), (22497), (22494), (4425), (4426), (22496);

INSERT INTO [electro].[ElectronicCorrespondenceInbox] ([UserId], [ElectronicCorrespondenceId], [CreatedAt])
SELECT [User].[UserId], [Corrs].[Id], GETDATE()
FROM [electro].[ElectronicCorrespondence] AS [Corrs], @USERS AS [User]
WHERE [Corrs].[Published] = 0;
```

Comment: Performance difference with 8 rows is going to be negligible either way. The former is difficult to parameterize for a variable amount of rows, the latter much easier. How are you calling this code?

Comment: You have other options to pass a list of values, which may be appropriate of the end game is a parameterized SQL query. These include: a table-valued parameter, xml (parsed with xml methods), json (parsed with `OPENJSON()`, delimited list (parsed with 'STRING_SPLIT()'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, **stop** using old-style join syntax - it's inprecise and error-prone; use modern explicite *join* syntax, see [Bad join habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Using a `temp table` in this scenario is unecessary and in most cases not desirable where an unknown number of rows are likely. SQL 2019 has something called *deferred table variable compilation* which can improve table-variable performance for ad-hoc queries, but is still problematic for cached execution plans.

This is because when you use a table variable, especially prior to SQL2019, SQL Server treats it as a variable in every sense, in that a variable can store a *single* value, and SQL Server assumes only 1 row will be present, whether it actually contains 1 row or 1 million rows.

This can lead to poor execution plans when joining to a table variable resulting in unsuitable join operations, table scan operations and underestimated memory grants resulting in tempdb usage, because it's always assumed to be a lightweight operation.

Your query is probably better written as follows, since you are introducing a cartesian product into your results it's always best to be explicit with the correct join syntax. This also assumes that you *need* to correlate the list of ID values with those that actually exist in the `Users` table, as your first query implies

```
insert into electro.ElectronicCorrespondenceInbox (UserId, ElectronicCorrespondenceId, CreatedAt)
select u.Id, ec.Id, GetDate()
from electro.ElectronicCorrespondence ec
cross join electro.Users u 
where ec.Published = 0
and u.id in (4438,15473,22497,22494,4425,4426,22496)
```

If you don't actually need this, as your second query implies, then you can simply include the list of `values` directly in your CTE without touching your `User` table

```
 with users as (
    select id from (values(4438),(15473),(22497),(22494),(4425),(4426),(22496))v(Id)
)
```

Also finally, if this is intended to be part of a procedure to which you pass a variable number of ID values, eg using a *table-type* parameter, you will likely find the best performance will result from inserting the values from your passed-in table-type parameter into a proper `#temporary table` and using that in your query.